# EXC_BAD_ACCESS by resetting NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to reset two NSTimers with a new TimeInterval.
It would be no problem if I know if they arent released before reseting them.

I can't work like this:

```
[timer invalidate];

if(startTimers == YES)
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval:...]
```

because I don't know if the timer was invalidated before I invalidate it.

And if I invalidate a released timer (on invalidation a timer gets released) I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you release the timer, also set its variable to nil.  Then `[timer invalidate]` will silently do nothing if timer is nil.

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

I already use [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683542/1293167)s solution and still get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

For me, a `dispatch_after` solved the problem:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    if ([_timer isValid]) [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil;
    [self timer];
});
```

*But it looks a bit dirty now, i know ...*